# First (or last) day of current month in a single variableless statement?

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, jasper-reports

I need to produce a simple string which should look like this:

```
01-03-2019 - 31-03-2019
```

The month and year should be of current date.

I have an expression like this:

```
new GregorianCalendar().getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " - " + 
new GregorianCalendar().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

But this produces a string like this:

```
1 - 31
```

How can I change the statement to get a full date in the format `mm-DD-yyyy`? It has to work without variables, as I am willing to use it as an variable expression in JasperSoft Studio...

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `GregorianCalendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Are you tied to some older Java version? A method reference might also help, is it out of bounds? A potential issue with the code you have is if it runs over midnight, the two calls to `new GregorianCalendar()` may produce different dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in a variableless way and in a single statement using Gregorian Calendar only then you can use the below code:

```
System.out.println(
        String.format("%2s", Calendar.getInstance().getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).replace(" ", "0") +
        "-" +
        String.format("%2s", (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)).replace(" ", "0") +
        "-" +
        Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) +
        " - " +
        String.format("%2s", Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).replace(" ", "0") +
        "-" +
        String.format("%2s", (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)).replace(" ", "0") +
        "-" +
        Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Comment: That totally solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: In that case why not just `String.format("%02d-%02d-%d - %02d-%02d-%d",
            Calendar.getInstance().getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),
            Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR))`? (still risking confusing results when run at midnight)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8's `time` APIs for this, e.g.:

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.now();
System.out.println(yearMonth.atDay(1));
System.out.println(yearMonth.atEndOfMonth());
```

If you want to display both in single line then you can use the following:

```
System.out.println(yearMonth.atDay(1) + " - " + yearMonth.atEndOfMonth());
```

**Update**

You can use `DateTimeFormatter` to format it using specified pattern, e.g.:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.now();
System.out.println(yearMonth.atDay(1).format(formatter) + " - " + yearMonth.atEndOfMonth().format(formatter));
```

Comment: A good start. It’s not in a single expression as requested, and doesn’t print in the requested format. Using `YearMonth` is a great idea.

Comment: @OleV.V. check the edits.

Comment: I know that GregorianCalendar and Date are deprecated but I am forced to use them, the reason is called Jaspersoft Studio :(

Comment: @dziki added another answer.

Comment: @OleV.V. edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, use LocalDate :

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
LocalDate startMonth = LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1);
LocalDate finishMonth = startMonth.plusMonths(1).minusDays(1);
System.out.println(startMonth.format(formatter) + " - " +  finishMonth.format(formatter));
```

Comment: Yes, but it’s not in one expression as requested. Otherwise a good answer.

Comment: You can wrap as many commands as you like into one!   ((Runnable) () -> { /* ... many comands ... ; */ }).run();

Comment: @Ilya How to use this code at report's template (jrxml file)?

Comment: @AlexK I'm not sure, but I think this expression will be calculated:   new Integer(((Supplier<String>) () -> {
            int x = 2;
            int y = 2;
            return "" + (x + y * x);
        }).get())

Comment: No, it is not working at template

Answer (score 0):

### Java 8 or later: java.time

```
    ((Supplier<String>) () -> {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu");
        YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Pyongyang"));
        return ym.atDay(1).format(dateFormatter) + " - " + ym.atEndOfMonth().format(dateFormatter);
    })
            .get();
```

Output when running just now:

> 01-03-2019 - 31-03-2019

I wanted to call `YearMonth.now` only once so I don’t risk getting two different results if running at midnight between two months. While it’s unlikely, it would also be *very* confusing.

### Java 6 or 7: ThreeTen Backport

```
    new Object() {
        String build() {
            DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu");
            YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Pyongyang"));
            return ym.atDay(1).format(dateFormatter) + " - " + ym.atEndOfMonth().format(dateFormatter);
        }
    }.build();
```

### Java 7 or earlier without external library (discouraged)

```
    new Object() {
        String build() {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            String startString = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            return startString + " - " + formatter.format(cal.getTime());
        }
    }.build();
```

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.